# Functioning if statement, improving it

Tags: if-statement

```
if (dog.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
    drink.don.setCost(8.75);
    drink.don.getType();
    drin.l.add(drink.don.getType());
    drink.c.add((double) coke.don.getCost());
    cokeprice = coke + fanta.don.getCost();
else if (dog.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
else catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    System.out.println("requires yes or no");
}
}
```

Ignore the stupid naming conventions had to change them, incase any class mates decided to steal anything ;p

I'm trying to get my if statement to allow the user input yes and do a condition, then if "no" has been entered then nothing happens just moves onto the next statement, then anything else is illegal and the program crashes.

Comment: What language is this? _This_ is a relevant tag, much more than `if-statement`.

Comment: It looks like Java. Definitely not JS or C/C++. If this is Java, `else catch` definitely is invalid. If this is a different language, this is most likely the case as well.

Comment: `else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("req..."); }`

Comment: @user3063201 Java is very similar to C#, so please look at my answer below. Comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language you are using, nor do I know what any of the methods you are using do, but here is an example of a similar statement in C#.

First, use a method to convert the user input to a true or false (boolean) value:

```
public static bool IsYes (string userInput)
{
    if (userInput == "yes')
    {
         return true;
    }
    else  if (userInput == "no")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new  CustomException();
    }
}
```

Next, you can take the result of `IsYes()` and use it for the if else statement:

```
if (IsYes(userInput))
{
    // code you want to execute if "yes" 
}
else
{
    // code you want to execute if "no"
}
```

Hopefully this code will give you an idea of how to use if-else statements, but in the future please explain your question more clearely. Remember, this is C#,  so although if statements are similar in almost all languages some of the other code will differ. Also, this is just an example, it won't do anything on its own.

Comment: No problem at all, and good luck programming, you'll be thinking in code before you know it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like throwing exceptions, especially if I expect that the user might type in something that I don't want. I'd rather do something like

```
if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
    // do yes
}
else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
    // do no
}
else {
    // Sorry, invalid input
}
```

Comment: Right, the main reason I did that in my answer was to give an example of if, else if, else and show a couple ways it can be used. Of course, you can always throw an exception and then catch, and have the catch block do something like what you are saying. I agree overall though, throw-catch can be bulkier and less clear sometimes.

Comment: if i had multiple if statements and had e.g. a variable that was a double which would calculate each if statements cost, as it goes up. Say if the first two if statements are different to the rest e.g. two cans of drinks. But, you can only have one. Is there anyway i can extend my first two if statements to say, if the first if statement is true then the next one has to be false. originally, i tried just saying in the second if statement if the variable is > 0 then don't let the next if statement be true, since it's adding on the cost each time.

Comment: Considering asking a new question. It is hard to imagine what you mean without a visual example.

Comment: @user3063201 I think what you need is nested if statements (one inside the other).